# Create grid layout with UIKIT

Tags: html, css, uikit

I've created the following layout with the use of Materialize CSS framework: 
[Link](https://codepen.io/Kajol2608/pen/dgymaq)

```css
.child-grid:nth-child(odd) {
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-left: 0px;
}

.child-grid:nth-child(even) {
    padding-right: 0px;
    padding-left: 10px;
}
.row .grid-item-left {
    padding-right: 20px;
}

.row .grid-item-right {
    padding-left: 20px;
}
.grid-item img {
    display: block;
    max-width: 100%;
}
.grid-item-right .row , .grid-item-left .row{
  margin-bottom: 8px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h3 class="center-align section-title">Destinations</h3>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col s6 m6 l6 grid-item-left">
      <div class="row">
        <img src="http://source.unsplash.com/1200x500/?usa" alt="" class="responsive-img">
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col s6 m6 l6 child-grid">
          <img src="http://source.unsplash.com/1200x500/?uk" alt="" class="responsive-img">
        </div>
        <div class="col s6 m6 l6 child-grid">
          <img src="http://source.unsplash.com/1200x500/?canada" alt="" class="responsive-img">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col s6 m6 l6 grid-item-right">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col s12 m6 l6 child-grid">
          <img src="http://source.unsplash.com/1200x500/?germany" alt="" class="responsive-img">
        </div>
        <div class="col s6 m6 l6 child-grid">
          <img src="http://source.unsplash.com/1200x500/?france" alt="" class="responsive-img">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <img src="http://source.unsplash.com/1200x500/?italy" alt="" class="responsive-img">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And had been trying to create similar using UIKIT css framework (ver. 3.0.0-rc.17) but I'm unable to create the similar layout. How can I achieve the layout that I'm looking for with UIKIT: [Link](https://codepen.io/Kajol2608/pen/bmGMBe)

Comment: @vishnu thanks for the suggestion. I'm trying to get result in 2nd link (UI KIT). Above code snippet is from the first link (Materialize CSS)

Answer (score 0):

In your code the issue is you are messing up with rows and column compared to material example, please have a look at the below working snippet which follows the structure on material link example. hope it help :)

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/uikit/3.0.0-rc.17/css/uikit.min.css">

<div class="uk-container">
  <h2 class="uk-heading-line uk-text-center"><span>DESTINATION</span></h2>
  <div class="uk-grid-collapse uk-child-width-1-2 uk-child-height-1-2 uk-grid" uk-grid="">
    <div class="uk-first-column">
      <div><img src="http://source.unsplash.com/620x243/?india" alt="" class="uk-padding-small"></div>
      <div class="uk-child-width-expand@s uk-text-center uk-grid uk-grid-collapse" uk-grid="">
        <div class="uk-first-column uk-panel uk-padding-small">
          <img src="http://source.unsplash.com/1200x500/?nepal" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="uk-panel uk-padding-small">
          <img src="http://source.unsplash.com/1200x500/?africa" alt="">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <div class="uk-child-width-expand@s uk-text-center uk-grid uk-grid-collapse" uk-grid="">
        <div class="uk-first-column uk-panel uk-padding-small">
          <img src="http://source.unsplash.com/1200x500/?usa" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="uk-panel uk-padding-small">
          <img src="http://source.unsplash.com/1200x500/?usa" alt="">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div><img src="http://source.unsplash.com/1200x500/?fiji" alt="" class="uk-padding-small"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing put the fault in the code. How to differentiate between rows and columns in UIKIT as there isn't specific documentation page on ROWS and COLUMNS in UIKIT unlike other farameworks.

Comment: grid is nothing but rows and columns, the issue you are facing is how to play around with `Nested grid` here u can get more info about UIKIT grids - https://getuikit.com/docs/grid#nested-grid